# What is "mathematical-programming"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are currently several questions tagged [mathematical-programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-programming), but this doesn't convey much meaning to me.  Are there better tags we could use?

Comment: I'm not even sure what the tag says in the first place. Any hints? (Or is it the obvious, "Mathematica is used to solve mathematical programs with a computer"? In that case, it should simply be called *programming* I guess.)

Comment: When I first saw the tag, I thought of the disciplines of linear programming, dynamic programming, and integer programming, that are all about optimization. But I was mistaken, maybe we could split this tag into "mathematics" and "programming"?

Comment: @Tobi: Not sure that you were the one that was mistaken. I think the phrase is just unfamiliar to people, so they incorrectly used it.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of googling shows that Wikipedia (accessed via google cache because of the SOPA protest) says that its an old term for programming optimization problems:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization

> An optimization problem can be represented in the following way << snip >>.
>   Such a formulation is called an optimization problem or a mathematical
>   programming problem
>   (a term not directly related to computer programming, 
>   but still in use for example in linear programming - see History below).

The page http://glossary.computing.society.informs.org/index.php?page=nature.html says that

> A mathematical program is an optimization problem of the form:
>
> Maximize $f(x): x in X, g(x) <= 0, h(x) = 0$
>
> where $X$ is a subset of $R^n$ and is in the domain of the functions,
>   $f$, $g$ and $h$, which map into real spaces. The relations, $x$ in
>   $X$, $g(x) <= 0$ and $h(x) = 0$ are called constraints, and $f$ is
>   called the objective function.

---

So, [mathematical-programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-programming) is just a certain type of constrained optimization problem. 
From this point of view, all [questions so far tagged with it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-programming) are tagged incorrectly.

We could make [mathematical-programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-programming) a synonym for [optimization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization),
however, the [optimization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) tag might get confused with [performance-tuning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning)...

Comment: It's for this reason I was advocating not using the optimization tag. The concept of mathematical optimization should use [tag:mathematical-optimization], and anything involving program optimization should be tagged [tag:performance-tuning]. I don't really understand why [tag:mathematical-programming] was used. I think people used it for tagging things that were related to mathematical formulas in a programming context.

Comment: @Mike: Exactly! And a lot more concise than my answer.